# Using the Callback Method on a View in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a master page with that code:

```
    public string CallbackMethod;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CallbackMethod = Page.ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference(this, "message", 
                         "Dodanie", "context", true);
    }

    /other code here/
```

then, in the View (which is based on that master page) I need to invoke the `CallbackMethod` string, but the problem is, the framework firstly renders the View, and then invokes the `Page_Load method`. As the obvious result, the error appears:

> `the name 'CallbackMethod' does not exist in the current context.`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You don't use ASP.NET `Page_Load` with ASP.NET MVC.  You don't use "CallBackMethod" in ASP.NET MVC either.  The paradigm is completely different.

It is not an event Driven Paradigm.

If you want to use Ajax, you can use it without invoking anything from the Webforms Framework. [Here is an example](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/05/19/ASPNETMVCAjaxBeginForm.aspx) of how to use Ajax with ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: My thoughts exactly - if you're relying on Page_Load in MVC you're doing something wrong

Comment: I started reading a nice post about Ajax + MVC http://www.nikhilk.net/Ajax-MVC.aspx but I don't see where I can get the AjaxController